# Grouping and labelling values in dataset in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to group my dataset into a unique label. Assume I have this data. Point and its neighbor point in column ABCD.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt0m9.jpg)

Array:

```
[[1 2]
 [2 1 4 5 7]
 [3 2]
 [4 2 10]
 [5 2 8]
 [6]
 [7 2 13]
 [8 5]
 [9]
 [10 4 1]
 [11 12]
 [12 11]
 [13 7]]
```

I am trying to summarize the data, and the desired result is as follow:

```
Label 1 = 1 2 4 5 7 3 10 8 13
Label 2 = 6
Label 3 = 9
Label 4 = 11 12
```

The point is when a value is already in a list with label, then give the value the existing label. But when the value is not in a list, then give it new label. I little bit confused how to call this problem, so I not found yet any same problem with mine. I would be very thankfull if somebody can give the python code or the pseudocode. Thank you

Comment: do you mean start a new label when first element of row is not exist in current labels, right ?

Comment: @phalanx Yes, but I think the algorithm must check each column of a row. When a value is found in a list, then stop and give the existing label. Otherwise give new label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working code, the result will be formated in a dictionary where keys are your data and values are labels like this: `{key: value, data:label}`

```
label=0
listOfLabels= dict()
for row in array:
    if not (any(x in row for x in listOfLabels.keys())):
        label+=1
    for i in (i for i in row if i not in listOfLabels.keys()):
        listOfLabels[i]=label
print(listOfLabels)
```

please let me know if it needs some clarifications

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. The code is working as my expectation.